# Do we know Snoke predates the Empire?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113070/what-does-kylo-ren-know-of-his-predecessor#comment271465_113071), DVK says:

> Snoke ... we still have no idea who he is but he predates Galactic Empire...

Having seen the film twice, I can't remember how we would know that, I don't recall references to Snoke's age or past history. But [DVK](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/976/dvk) is knowledgeable about Star Wars in general, is there something that tells us this? In the film, or the novelisation, or...?

Comment: @DVK Tricky one. The answer to the other question does mention the pertinent fact, but way down at the end and easy to miss. So *technically* it's a duplicate, but it's a very edge case. I think I'll VTRO.

Comment: @DVK Personally I think you probably shouldn't have closehammered (and I realise you didn't mean to), but now that you *have*, leave it to non-hammer-wielders to decide whether to reopen. Others may disagree :-)

Comment: @randal'thor - January 1st. Not enough people might be around. I'll undupe, and let others clean up in case my original thinking was correct.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*(Spelling "Snoke" correctly let me find the answer. Doh!)*

Yes. Well, we know he *claims* to predate the Empire.

In [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111028/32547), DVK quotes the novelisation by Alan Dean Foster, in which Snoke says:

> “Kylo Ren, **I watched the Galactic Empire rise, and then fall**. The gullible prattle on about the triumph of truth and justice, of individualism and free will. As if such things were solid and real instead of simple subjective judgments. The historians have it all wrong. It was neither poor strategy nor arrogance that brought down the Empire. You know too well what did.”

So he either predates the Empire, or wants Kylo to believe he does.

Comment: Any objections if I close this as a duplicate of that answer? (i'll flag for dupe anyway, but if I do it myself it's immediate)

Comment: @DVK: If that would be the way things are done here, sure. Where I'm active, on SO, we probably wouldn't call it a duplicate, because that's just one small part of an answer that's mostly about something else. E.g., while that answer does answer the question, it's almost in passing, buried at the end of a discussion of somethign else. But different SE sites have slightly different thresholds, you'd know better than I where that threshold is here.

Comment: It's on Meta, the rules are if the answer A2 of Q2 answers Q1 (including part of answer A2), it's a dupe. I'm not always terribly thrilled with that rule but I can see its wisdom.

Comment: @DVK: Yeah, again, I wouldn't expect all questions that happen to get answered in passing by one small part of an answer that's fundamentally answering something else to be dupes of that other question. But hey, dupes do broaden the search surface, so.. :-)

Comment: Yep, that's basically the rationale, exactly

Comment: @DVK: That's not quite what I meant (that rationale is valid for actual dupes, yes), but it's not important.

Comment: btw it is even mentioned in the film (same phrase) as far as I remember

Comment: @Thomas: Yeah -- when I found DVK's answer, it sounded familiar. Since I haven't read the book, that had to be the film and I just didn't clock it. :-)